# What books would you recommend to understand gauge theories?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, physics, gauge-theory

I am a math student who got interested in the topics above also I want to learn about the Dirac matter the spinors the Einsteins GR and the Yang- Mills Maxwell Anderson -Higgs theories and models and general gauge theories and wants to understand them. What are some good introductory books for people like me where they have some mathematical understanding but not physics background. I need these books to describe them mathematical and not just explain them in general.

Comment: [*Mathematical Gauge Theory* by Mark Hamilton](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319684383) is great. Also, I watched the Atiyah Lecture this Monday by J. P. Bourguignon, someone asked him in the end for references and he mentioned he wrote [a recent book on spinors](https://www.ems-ph.org/books/book.php?proj_nr=194&titleindex=1) with several collaborators (I need to find the time to take a look at it myself)...

Comment: Thanks for the answer